# Reason behind strange per-item discounts for bundled products?

Tags: orders, bundled-product, ee-1.13, shopping-cart-price-rules

When bundled products, which have simple products associated to them, are purchased, and a cart-wide discount (Shopping Cart Price Rules) is given, the per-item discounts are very strangely divided up. See screen shot for an example. Is there a reason to this strange calculations?

EE 1.13 vanilla instance.

- Discounts seem to be divided according to the `Price` column.
  [image]
- Discount is split unevenly. (first bundled product is shipped, but it's irrelevant)
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento splits the discount "fair" over all order items.

So 10$ discount should be split this way:

```
Case 1:
1x Chocolate 10$ - 5$
1x Beer      10$ - 5$

Case 2:
3x Chocolate 30$ - 7.5$
1x Beer      10$ - 2.5$
```

I think what your problem is, is the fact, that magento throws the whole discount on the first item on bundle products.

```
Case 3:
3x Chocolate Set 30$ - 7.5$
     1x Swiss Chcocolate    -7.5$
     1x German Chocolate    no discount
1x Beer          10$ - 2.5$
```

Comment: In my screenshot, though, I don't see a pattern as to how the discounts are assigned. The 3.33$ discount, which is 66% of the whole discount, appears on the first item of the second bundled product. I've tried a few different configurations of bundle product purchases, and I honestly could not find a pattern. Any ideas? My next step is to just look at the code base when I get the chance..

Comment: Of course, the first product costs 10$, the second 20$, so the first gets 33% and the second gets 66%, and these 66$ are put on the first part of the bundle.

Comment: But there first item is x3 qty. I suppose it ignores it. I'll put up another strange one!

Comment: You are right. I'm out - I thougt I understood it :D Please post an explanation when you are back out of the digged hole :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to upgrade to 1.9.3.0 because there are several bug fixes applied to the discount rules in combination with bundle products and the bundle products percentage prices. If you are going to upgrade please make sure you first read the release notes so you know what will change and what has to be tested.